# Transparent stripe blocking the view of edit mode selection

Tags: interface, error

You can see it on the screenshot. It's always stays in the middle of viewport. Is it a visual bug?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share the blend? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Yep, edited the post.

Comment: I have looked at your file and it seems as if everything is fine with the texture. In Cycle and Eevee. Try the texture on a new cube and use "Smart UV Project".

Comment: Added another screenshot. The strip is there even without any textures. Probably a glitch, should i try reinstalling blender?

Comment: It looks like clipped render view, but ussually you can see a red border of it and the rest of scene is in solid view ... hm ... I dont see the line on my PC. What display mode you use?

Comment: The strip is even over the grid, not only on the cube. Try to open a new blender file and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, i didnt even notice... The issue is still there when i open new blender files.

Comment: In this case I would recommend a clean removal of Blender, download the latest version from Blender.org and update your graphic driver.

Comment: ok, thanks for answers.

Comment: However, first try to open a new Blender file and see if the issue is still present.

Comment: Before that try Ctrl+Alt+B in 3Dview Editor (in case it is saved in StartUp file setup). Or File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings

Comment: I was also thinking that it might be a render selection, however, it would have had a red outline.

Comment: The stripe actually disappeared when i loaded factory settings. Thanks